# Easy to read font for windows console that supports all character sets

Tags: fonts, windows-console

Can someone please recommend a font that:

- will work in windows console (TrueType monospace)
- supports all character sets
- is easy to read in the console

Last point is important, otherwise in Windows 10 console I can already select SimSun-ExtB that seems to support all languages. But it looks really ugly and hard to read.

Comment: You should be able to link Consolas to other TrueType or OpenType fonts such as NSimSun. Font linking is defined in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink` as a Multi-String value such as "Consolas" that lists linked fonts such as "SIMSUN.TTC,NSimSun". Follow the existing examples. Then in a console you can switch to codepage 437. Select Consolas as the font and switch back to 936 (or whatever).

Comment: I only recommend this if you're using an East-Asian system locale to be able to use a console codepage such as 936. The console's display of full-width glyphs is buggy in a Western locale such as codepage 437. It seems to determine the display region for rendered text based on the calculated width assuming only half-width characters, so rendered text that has full-width characters gets cut off.